# Prolog equivalence operator

Tags: prolog

I am implementing Checkers in SWI-Prolog, and created a predicate that checks if a given move is legal:

```
check_piece_move(white, X/Y, NewX/NewY) :-
    AcceptedX1 is X+1, AcceptedX2 is X-1,           % white can move to either next or previous column
    AcceptedY is Y+1,                               % and one row upwards
    (AcceptedX1 == NewX; AcceptedX2 == NewX),       % make sure NewX is acceptable
    AcceptedY == NewY.                              % make sure NewY is acceptable
```

This predicate works well if I suffice all the variables in advance (i.e, give X/Y and NewX/NewY). However, I now want it to perform the opposite - given X/Y, it will suffice NewX/NewY with a valid possibility.
What can I change to do so?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you know what is acceptable and what not? Not immediately clear from your question or your code. Do you have a board size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `==` (which succeeds if terms are identical so in your case it fails when NewsX is variable) with unification `=`:

```
check_piece_move(white, X/Y, NewX/NewY) :-
    AcceptedX1 is X+1, AcceptedX2 is X-1,          
    AcceptedY is Y+1,                               
    (AcceptedX1 = NewX; AcceptedX2 = NewX),      
    AcceptedY = NewY.
```

Example:

```
?- check_piece_move(white,1/2,NewX/NewY).
NewX = 2,
NewY = 3 ;
NewX = 0,
NewY = 3.
```

An even better approach would be by using CLPFD:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

check_piece_move(white, X/Y, NewX/NewY) :-
       abs(X-NewX) #= 1,
       Y+1 #= NewY.
```

This works if any of X/Y or NewX/NewY are provided:

```
?- check_piece_move(white,X/Y,3/1).
X = 4,
Y = 0 ;
X = 2,
Y = 0.

?- check_piece_move(white,3/1,NewX/NewY).
NewX = NewY, NewY = 2 ;
NewX = 4,
NewY = 2.

?- check_piece_move(white,X/Y,3/1).
X = 4,
Y = 0 ;
X = 2,
Y = 0.

?- check_piece_move(white,3/Y,NewX/1).
Y = 0,
NewX = 2 ;
Y = 0,
NewX = 4.

?- check_piece_move(white,X/1,3/NewY).
X = 4,
NewY = 2 ;
X = NewY, NewY = 2.

?- check_piece_move(white,X/Y,NewX/NewY).
NewX+1#=X,
Y+1#=NewY ;
X+1#=NewX,
Y+1#=NewY.
```

Comment: Pieces can still fall off the board. I guess it would be a bit better if the board size was also given as an argument.

Comment: And you can simply unify `Y` with `NewY` in the head.

Comment: But he wants to unify AccptedY=Y+1 with NewY so he needs calculate AcceptedY?

Comment: Boris, I do have some other checks which include identifying pieces that fall of the board. Right now I focused just on the unification, and tried to make the problem clear :-) Thank you both.